# Combinations of array when x values are dropped

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations

I'm implementing a method to get cross validation folds and have a list of numpy arrays with the size s. I want to use x arrays as test folds and therefore s-x arrays as training folds. For a proper cross validation method, every array should be a test fold once with all combinations of the other x-1 arrays  as a test fold. By doing it this way I withhold complete arrays from the training. I want to test the transferability of regressors trained with the data from s-x arrays to x arrays.
This problem can be reduced to a problem all possible combinations of an numpy array of size s are generated when any x values are droped.

example code:

```
s = 4
x = 2
array = np.arange(0, s)
drop_out = x
combinations(array, drop_out)
## output (I hope, I didn't forget a combination)
array([[2, 3], [1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1]])
```

Is there any pre-build function to do this? The only solution I came up with so far is by using x-loops to do this. But then x is not a parameter.

I'm looking forward to suggestions.

Best,
Jannis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use itertools to generate combinations:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


def combinations(a, drop_out):
    """
    >>> print(combinations(range(4), 2))
    [[0 1]
     [0 2]
     [0 3]
     [1 2]
     [1 3]
     [2 3]]
    """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    return np.array([r for r in itertools.combinations(a, a.size - drop_out)])
```